# JSONObject not working in java eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, json, eclipse

I am trying to create a JSONArray on java using eclipse as my IDE. However, I am unable to create a JSONArray object there is always a red line under JSONArray. Do i need to import anything because the red lines did not give me any suggestions as to what to import.

```
package mypackage;

public class Test {

    static void printFile(String path){
        String lines = "[qwer,asdf,zxcv]";

        JsonArray a =new JSONArray(lines);


    }
```

Comment: Yes there will be an error or message. Find it and post it.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
```

Comment: But even when i add this line, there is a red line under org.json telling me that org.json cannot be resolved

Comment: External library. Use maven or gradle dependency management tools. I believe this is the library you need: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1

Comment: Id also read this article: https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the objects in your code: one is a JsonArray and the other is JSONArray. Those two are not the same thing. Case matters.